# What is a mixed spice with respect to a cake?

Tags: cake, spices

> 1 tsp mixed spice

http://www.maryberry.co.uk/recipes/baking/whole-orange-spice-cake

What does mixed spice constitute of in terms of cake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixed spice is a blend you find in the UK. It's a mix of cinnamon, ground coriander, nutmeg, ginger, and cloves. Some recipes call for mace, caraway, and/or allspice as well. It's a bit like garam masala, there's no set blend. It's as simple as mixing together equal quantities of each, although you may want to add double the mace if you opt for it.

Comment: If you want a store bought substitute in the US, it sounds similar to pumpkin pie spice, except maybe the coriander.

Comment: That sounds about right actually now that I think about it.

Comment: Corriander is quite odd in that mix; did you perhaps mean cardamom?

Comment: I know it sounds odd, but it's almost always in mixed spice. Cardamom isn't one of the traditional ingredients.